# Installing issues | unable to open /dev/sda and /dev/sdb

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, ssd, laptop, raid

I am installing Ubuntu 14.04 from a USB drive. It boots into the installation and after selecting `Install Ubuntu` the loading screen appears and stops there.
Pressing the left arrow key brings me to a text screen which only shows:

```
Unable to open /dev/sda
Unable to open /dev/sdb
```

I'm trying to install this on an MSI GT70 2OC with a RAID 0 mSATA array and 750GB HDD. Windows would still install just fine but I would prefer a Linux distribution on the system.

Comment: may be these are not mounted. Boot into live USB and check this

Comment: There are two common causes why a distro fails to install. many times the errors are only confusing and do not point to the actual error. The causes are 1. The ISO is corrupted; check for the md5sum and shasums. 2.The software used for creating bootable drive is not working correctly; try another software.

Comment: I have tried mounting on a live version on usb install with pendrive and it would freeze as well, unable to open /dev/sda and /dev/sdb. So far I have tried the SSD's without raid but to no success.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick guess: 
I know of IRST (intel rapid storage technology) causing problems with RAID installs. 
Try testing whether or not your BIOS has IRST enabled. If so, try resetting/disabling it and create your RAID0 using ubuntu installation medium.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: while the installer is booting in UEFI mode, press buttons to clear any splash screen so you can see errors occurring.  Then as soon as `Unable to open /dev/*` messages start, yank the USB drive and plug it into any other port.  After hanging a bit reconnecting the drive, it should complete booting successfully.

---

I cannot fathom what chain of incompetence creates the problem for which this could actually be a fix, but I've tried countless variations of bios configuration, hardware choice, and method of preparing the USB stick, all to no avail.  And I'm pretty annoyed at the endless stream of help that *only* considers user error when the only constant is Ubuntu itself, spanning nearly a decade of releases.

But there you have it.  If you have gotten so far as to *start* a UEFI boot (most easily confirmed by seeing a boot menu in native display resolution), then I strongly suggest trying a few variations of this before wasting countless hours trying variations on installer image setup and/or bios settings.

Note: making matters even worse, this *decade old* problem will make the image seem broken and offer no UEFI boot mode after one boot (including ones where you go to firmware settings instead or similar), until you have moved it to a different USB port.  It's all lies.  Do better, Canonical!